# How to wrap element in a div after creating it via the "jQuery method"?

Tags: jquery

**Desired Output**

```
<div class="dropdown_container"> 
<div class="dropdown" style="top: 50px; left: 50px;">test</div>
</div>
```

**Current Output**

```
<div class="dropdown" style="top: 50px; left: 50px;">test</div>
```

**What I've Tried**

```js
var $dropdown = $(`
<div class="dropdown">
test
</div>
`);

$dropdown.offset({
  top: '50',
  left: '50'
});

$dropdown.wrap("<div class=\"dropdown_container\"></div>");

$("body").append($dropdown);
```

```css
.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
}

.dropdown_container {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `$('.dropdown_container').html($dropdown);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear to me why you don't just include the markup for that outer `div` originally, but the reason `wrap` isn't working is that it expects to operate on elements already in the DOM.

You can just create the `div` and append your other `dvi` to it:

```
$("body").append($("<div>").append($dropdown));
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry maybe i didn't understand but why don't do directly

```
var $dropdown = $(`
<div class=\"dropdown_container\">
<div class="dropdown">
test
</div>
</div>
`);
```

??

Comment: I was thinking same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try code below. All things in only one line:

```
$(function(){
    $('<div class="dropdown" style="top: 50px; left: 50px;">test</div>')/*your $dropdown*/.appendTo($('<div class="dropdown_container"></div>').appendTo($("body")));
});
```

Try it [online](https://jsbin.com/sifucosino/edit?output)

---

**But** if you like your solution (`.wrap(..) method`), code below will be useful (although I suggest you my first way because that adds elements to `body` after create them and is lighter too):

```
 $(function(){
    $('<div class="dropdown" style="top: 50px; left: 50px;">test</div>')/*your $dropdown*/.appendTo($("body")).wrap($('<div class="dropdown_container"></div>'));
 });
```

And [its fiddle](https://jsbin.com/nesiwemimu/1/edit?output)